# Comparing Different cells in two Rows in sql

Tags: sql, triggers

I have two rows in the same table. I want to show the difference between these two rows like shown in the picture. I am trying to do that in an update trigger between inserted and deleted tables. My goal is to capture changes in the table by trigger like this. The point is I need only changed cells How can I do that?

[image: Example rows]

Comment: Tag the dbms used, since most products have their own, non-ANSI SQL, trigger implementations

Answer (score 0):

You should use cursor for that case. By using cursor you can store each cell values to variables and then you can compare.

Comment: but there is too much columns. solution should be flexible, I will use it for many tables